# Using MergeObjects without overwriting subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to merge two fields in my aggregation pipeline.

I want to transform this:

```
{
   "a": 1,
   "b": {
      "first": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value"
      },
      "second": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value"
      },
      "third": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value"
      },
      "fiftieth": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value"
      }
   },
   "c": {
      "first": {
          "property_x": "some_value",
          "property_y": "some_value"
      },
      "second": {
          "property_x": "some_value",
          "property_y": "some_value"
      },
      "fiftieth": {
          "property_x": "some_value",
          "property_y": "some_value"
      }
   }
}
```

Into this, without having to specify every key listed under "b":

```
{
   "a": 1,
   "b": {
      "first": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value",
          "property_x": "some_value",
          "property_y": "some_value"
      },
      "second": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value",
          "property_x": "some_value",
          "property_y": "some_value"
      },
      "third": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value"
      },
      "fiftieth": {
          "property_a": "some_value",
          "property_b": "some_value",
          "property_c": "some_value",
          "property_x": "some_value",
          "property_y": "some_value"
      }
   }
}
```

In the documentation for `mergeObjects`, it states:

> mergeObjects overwrites the field values as it merges the documents. If documents to merge include the same field name, the field, in the resulting document, has the value from the last document merged for the field.

How can I merge the subdocuments of fields b and c without specifying every key (there are 85 keys in my real world use case). Also, field c may not have every key listed under b. Or is this not possible?

Comment: Is it certain that none of the fields in `b` or `c` will contain anything other than a document?

Comment: Yes. Fields b and c only contain documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$objectToArray` to convert the objects to k,v pairs, combine and `$unwind` them, `$group` by the key name and merge the documents, then `$group` by the _id to collect the keys back together.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      combined: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {$objectToArray: "$b"},
          {$objectToArray: "$c"}
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$unwind: "$combined"},
  {$group: {
      _id: {_id: "$_id", key: "$combined.k"},
      doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"},
      v: {$mergeObjects: "$combined.v"}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      doc: {$first: "$doc"},
      combined: {$push: {
          k: "$_id.key",
          v: "$v"
      }}
  }},
  {$addFields: {"doc.b": {$arrayToObject: "$combined"}}},
  {$project: {
    combined: 0,
    "doc.c": 0
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$doc"}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Iz2Ggm16d_)

Comment: This solution works. I really appreciate the help! Thank you so much!